# take into (an) account

Tags: articles

Coming from an articleless language, I often have problems with things like this:

> take something into account
>
> take something into **an** account

Are both phrases correct? If yes, is there a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Take something into account/take account of something:** notice or consider it, pay attention to it

"Take something into **an** account" is **incorrect**.

> We will definitely *take* your contribution to this company *into account* while taking the decision.
>
> We will definitely *take into account* your contribution to this company while taking the decision.
>
> We will definitely *take account* of your contribution to this company while taking the decision.

Comment: "Take something into an account" is not incorrect, it just means something different. e.g. "I will take payment into an account set up especially for the transaction".

Comment: @MattЭллен Yes, you are correct. I overlooked that.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. But shouldn't it be "... _in_ an account set up..."?

Comment: Both are valid.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom 'take into account' dates back to the mid 1500's, and means that something should be given consideration.  Whereas to 'take smth into an account' is a direct instruction.